# How to take the resposne from one ng controller to another ng cntroller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am a newbie to ng. Here, I have a scenario where I need to take the response received from success to another controller. I have tried the below code but I am not able to achieve my target.

CODE:

```
            $scope.received = function(){

                $http({
                    url : "/generic/getdata",
                    method : 'GET',
                    }).success(function(data) { 
                    //The data received here I need t take to mydataController
                    $location.path('/success');

                })

                 when('/success', {
                templateUrl: 'ngtemplates/success/success.html',
                controller: 'mydataController'
              }).
       app.controller('mydataController',
    [ '$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http,$location) { 
           //I want the success data here in some function
             }]);
```

Please, help me

Answer (score 0):

you can use a service for your purpose.

**SERVICE :**

```
myApp.factory('dataService', function() {

var _data;

this.setData = function(someData) {
 _data = someData; // better use angular.copy() function
}

return {
    data : _data;
  }
});
```

**HTTP CALL :**

```
$http({
url : "/generic/getdata",
method : 'GET',
}).success(function(data) { 
//The data received here I need t take to mydataController

// before using dataService, make sure you inject it to the controller
dataService.setData(data);

$location.path('/success');

});
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
app.controller('mydataController',
    [ '$scope', '$http',function($scope, $http,$location, dataService) { 
           //I want the success data here in some function

      var someData = dataService.data;
    }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 solutions. you can make a Service or use events.

```
$http({
   url : "/generic/getdata",
   method : 'GET',
   }).success(function(data) { 
     $rootScope.$broadcast('dataReceived', data);
     $location.path('/success');
});
```

In mydataController:

```
$rootScope.$on('dataReceived', function(e, data) {
 // do something with the data
}
```

Or you can make a service to share the data between the two.

```
angular.module('demo').service('myDataService', function() {

this.data = null;

this.setData = function(data) {
this.data = data;
}

});
```

in the controller:

```
  $http({
       url : "/generic/getdata",
       method : 'GET',
       }).success(function(data) { 
         myDataService.setData(data);
         $location.path('/success');
    });
```

In mydataController:

```
$scope.something = myDataService.data;
```